# How to detect current repository type and location?

Tags: git, bash, mercurial

I am looking to write a simple bash script that I could use to detect the scm repository (git or hg) in which I am currently located (current directory).

Mainly the logic is to find first `.git` or `.hg` directory starting from the currently directory. To be correct, the logic should stop at the filesystem boundary.

The main problem now seems to be the detection of the filesystem boundary.

Current implementation:

```
LOC=`pwd`

while [ $LOC != '/' ]; do
  if [ -d "$LOC/.git" ]; then
    require_clean_work_tree_git
    break
  elif [ -d "$LOC/.hg" ]; then
    require_clean_work_tree_hg
    break
  else
    LOC=`dirname $LOC`
  fi
done
```

The problem with current implementation is that it will cross the FS boundaries, which may trigger some undesired bugs.

Answer (score 6):

This functionality is already implemented in git and hg. Why not to use their implementation?

```
if git status &> /dev/null ; then
    repo=git
    root=$( git rev-parse --show-toplevel )
elif hg status &> /dev/null ; then
    repo=hg
    root=$( hg root )
else
    echo Not in a repo. >&2
    exit 1
fi
echo $repo "$root"
```

Comment: I agree this is the way forward.  However the OP also wants the root of the repo displayed.

Comment: In git, you can use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, in hg, it is simple `hg root`.

Comment: Sure.  You might want to add it to your answer to provide a complete solution?